# Is it possible to receive a message from a webchat (on a website) and forward this message to Whatsapp using Twilio?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I'm looking into the Twilio Whatsapp API docs, and cannot find anywhere if it is possible to receive a message sent from a website webchat on a Whatsapp Business Account?

I would like to develop the following:
a user is on my website, and has a quesiton. He/she then opens the chatbox and types their question (non-whatsapp). This message is then sent to the Whatsapp Business Account of the Client and they can talk back and forth with the user.

I hope I have been clear enough, please let me know if I need to supply more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe that this would be possible to do for one user messaging at a time, but practically and at scale, not really useful.

If you have a user sending a message through a website that is then delivered to a user through WhatsApp, you could build an application that allowed the user on WhatsApp reply to the message and relay that back to the website.

However, if you have one WhatsApp number registered to send messages on behalf of your application and multiple users were sending messages through the website, all the messages would come from that one WhatsApp number and it would be practically impossible for the user responding in WhatsApp to know who they were responding to.

It would likely be better to connect your users via webchat within the web application and use WhatsApp to notify the the client that there are new messages awaiting their reply.